# How do I match my req.body from the client to one of three variables on my server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm setting up my SaaS pricing table using stripe and have three different pricing options users can choose from on the client side so my `req.body` comes through with the variable ID of whichever option the user selects:

- Basic price variable **basicPriceId** comes through as `{ basicPriceId: 'basicPriceId' }`
- Scaled price variable **scaledPriceId** comes through as `{ scaledPriceId: 'scaledPriceId' }`
- Enterprise price variable **enterprisePriceId** comes through as `{ enterprisePriceId: 'enterprisePriceId' }`

I'd like to match those selections with the variable I've setup on the server side so I can push the product key ID contained *within* each variable to stripe through the server.

**Controller function on server**

```
const { basicPriceId, scaledPriceId, enterprisePriceId ,webUrl, priceId, stripeSecret, stripeWebhookSecret } = require('../production');

module.exports.createCheckoutSession = async (req, res) => {
    const { currency } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    const selectedPriceId = ???
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                mode: "subscription",
                customer: req.user.stripe_customer[currency],
                line_items: [
                    {
                        price: selectedPriceId,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                ],
                success_url: `${webUrl}/users/${req.user._id}/activations/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
                cancel_url: `${webUrl}/canceled.html`,
                });
                return res.redirect(303, session.url);

        } catch (e) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({
                error: {
                    message: e.message,
                }
            });
        }
    }
    req.flash('error', "You must login before changing billing");
    res.render('/login');
}
```

How do I get my variable `selectedPriceId` to equal whichever variable the user selects so I can pass it into my `line_item` for `price`?

Comment: I would question why you are formatting the price IDs in that way when sending. The format `{selectedPriceId: 'basicPriceId' }` for example, would make more sense. And would allow you to more easily extract the value in your controller function.

Comment: Ahhh, okay great call, thanks @AlexGourlay . I fixed it but still struggling with how to set `selectedPriceId` equal to the server side price IDs?

Comment: If you're now sending in the format `{selectedPriceId: 'basicPriceId' }`, then you can just destructure the selected ID at the start of your function. `const { currency, selectedPriceId } = req.body;`. You will then be able to supply selectedPriceId in your stripe function call.

Comment: Thanks @AlexGourlay that worked but now the `basicPriceId` is being cast as a string in `line_item: price` field and not the underlying variable. Is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: Where are you storing the actual prices? You will need to store them on the server somewhere.

Comment: In my .env file, then I pass them to the server using `require('../production');` - added code to the main question at the top of the controller function @AlexGourlay

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to vscode autopilot (and some client side help from @Alex Gourlay in the comments) but I had to create a mapping at the top and then pass the value down into the function.

For the client side changes I tweaked the id for all of the client side inputs to be the same as `id="selectedPriceId"` and updated the corresponding value for each to be either `value="basic"`, `scaled`, or `enterprise`. This way the code would come through as below:

- Basic price variable **basicPriceId** comes through as { selectedPriceId: 'basic' }
- Scaled price variable **scaledPriceId** comes through as { selectedPriceId: 'scaled' }
- Enterprise price variable **enterprisePriceId** comes through as { selectedPriceId: 'enterprise' }

Then for my controller function I created a mapping at the top and passed that down into the logic.

**Controller function**

```
const { basicPriceId, scaledPriceId, enterprisePriceId ,webUrl, stripeSecret, stripeWebhookSecret } = require('../production');

module.exports.createCheckoutSession = async (req, res) => {
    const { currency, selectedPriceId } = req.body;

    // create deconstructed object to map selectedPriceId to the correct priceId
    const priceIdMap = {
        basic: basicPriceId,
        scaled: scaledPriceId,
        enterprise: enterprisePriceId
    }
    const priceId = priceIdMap[selectedPriceId];

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                mode: "subscription",
                customer: req.user.stripe_customer[currency],
                line_items: [
                    {
                        price: priceId,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                ],
                success_url: `${webUrl}/users/${req.user._id}/activations/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
                cancel_url: `${webUrl}/canceled.html`,
                });
                return res.redirect(303, session.url);

        } catch (e) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({
                error: {
                    message: e.message,
                }
            });
        }
    }
    req.flash('error', "You must login before changing billing");
    res.render('/login');
}
```

**Note that I also removed the `priceId` variable from the top because it's now declared in the logic of the function.